# Google cloud function doesn't trigger on crashlytics velocityAlert

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have 3 cloud functions for integrations with crashlytics events. They contain the same logic but are bound to different events (onNew, onVelocityAlert and onRegressed). As I can see from logs only NewIssueEvent(onNew) works well. VelocityAalerts and Regressed events are never invoked although notifications about these events come to e-mail. What am I doing wrong?

See code below:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const rp = require('request-promise');

function sendEvent(event) {
    return rp({
        method: 'POST',
        uri: functions.config().crashlytics.crash_collector_url,
        body: event,
        json: true,
    });
}

exports.VelocityAlertEvent = functions.crashlytics.issue().onVelocityAlert(async (issue) => {
    await processEvent(issue, 'VelocityAlertEvent')
});

exports.NewIssueEvent = functions.crashlytics.issue().onNew(async (issue) => {
    await processEvent(issue, 'NewIssueEvent')
});

exports.RegressedEvent = functions.crashlytics.issue().onRegressed(async (issue) => {await processEvent(issue, 'RegressedEvent')});

const processEvent = async (event, type) =>{
    if (isActualEvent(event)) {
        await sendEvent(event);
        console.log(`Posted ${type} ${event.issueId} successfully to crash collector`);
    }
    else{
        console.log(`It's old event. Do nothing`);
    }
}

const isActualEvent = (event) =>{
    const {appInfo} = event;
    const {appName, latestAppVersion} = appInfo;
    const version = latestAppVersion &&  parseFloat(latestAppVersion.split(' ')[0]);
    console.log(`Event appName: ${appName} version: ${version}`);
    return appName === 'MyApp' && version > 666.123
}
```

Comment: have you tried to add "console.log" lines to track if you call goes through the functions?

Comment: Same issue with me cloud function does not trigger. Any idea?

Comment: Caution: The Firebase Crashlytics integration with Cloud Functions for Firebase is deprecated. On October 1, 2020, any Crashlytics functions you have deployed will stop being triggered. I found this one/